# SolR: faceting on TextField

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'm working with a SolR cloud 6.5.0 installation.
My goal is to retrieve all terms that co-occur with my search terms, rank them by count, and take the top-N.
To do that I've defined a field of type `text_en_facets` that defines a TextField with a `PatternTokenizer` and few other things (complete definition at the end of the post).

Now my instance contains quite some data: the field contains 1.3M unique terms and, as a result, I get the following error:

```
o.a.s.s.FastLRUCache Error during auto-warming of key:payload_en_facets:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Too many values for UnInvertedField faceting on field…
```

I noticed that [other people had the same issue](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/java-lang-IllegalStateException-Too-many-values-for-UnInvertedField-faceting-on-field-content-td4218197.html) and I was wondering if there are any news about best practices and/or way to circumvent this limitation. 
Would be awesome if I wouldn't have to re-indexing the data or analyse my documents manually to use `StrField`s.

I've already tried different configurations of the `facet.method`, `facet.limit`, and `facet.mincount` but this did not solve the problem.
Any other idea?

```
    <fieldType name="text_en_facets" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <!-- recognises e-mail addresses, urls, #-tags and @-mentions, alphanumeric words (possibly containing inner periods) -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory"
                   pattern="(?U)([\w-\.]+@[\w-\.]+)|(https?:\S+)|((\s|^)[@#]\w+)|(\w+(\.\w+)?)" group="0"/>
        <!-- there might be tokens containing trailing/leading white spaces -->
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" format="snowball"
                words="stopwords/stopwords_en.txt,stopwords/stopwords_en_nltk.txt,stopwords/stopwords_en_twitter.txt"
                ignoreCase="true"/>
        <!-- kills urls -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(?U)https?:\S+" replacement=""/>
        <!-- kills numbers -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(?U)^[0-9.,']+$" replacement=""/>
        <!-- kills meaningless tokens  -->
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="1024"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Did you try the patch from the answer?

Comment: hi @MatsLindh, not yet

Answer (score 2):

It is a limitation of the internal structures used when faceting on Text-fields.

- It should be possible to circumvent it with `facet.method=enum`, which will be very slow in this scenario
- You might try to split the index into a lot of shards, but the chances of that working depends on your index its term-distribution. Also, it will probably lower performance

I have located the problem and written a fix (code at https://github.com/tokee/lucene-solr/tree/uninvert-optimize), but that does not help you at the moment. I am in the process of getting it into Solr, so watch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11240 for updates.

Updated 20170824: @Alberto I have added the patch to Solr, but due to timing issues, it will not be part of the upcoming 6.6.1 and 7.0 releases. If you need it now, I am fairly sure that the patch at issue SOLR-11240 applies cleanly to Solr 6.5+ source code.

Updated 20171017: @Alberto The fix is part of Solr 7.1 that was released earlier today. If you are willing to upgrade, this should solve your problem.

Comment: sorry, @Toke Eskildsen, i've just read your updates. For the moment my team decided to create new collections by month. I'll have a look at the patch ;)